# Could a child table with a foreign constraint be a temporary table?

Tags: mysql

When attempting to do so, I get the following error:

> 1005 - Can't create table 'bidjunction.parent_table' (errno: 150)

I expect it is because real table `super_table` doesn't exist, only TEMPORARY TABLE `super_table`.

Is it possible to do so?  Where is it documented?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS super_table (
id INT NOT NULL,
data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_table (
id INT NOT NULL,
data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_parent_super
FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES super_table (id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not, it's not possible, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) it is documented

> The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child table. The parent and
>   child tables must use the same storage engine. They must not be
>   TEMPORARY tables

Comment: Thank you.  Yes it is surely shown there.  I was looking at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html, and it wasn't discussed.